# Specifying a :format in link_to doesn't work in rails 3.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, link-to

I'm moving a project from rails 3.1 to rails 3.2.2 and I have this:

```
= link_to 'CSV', :action => 'list', :search => @search, :format => 'csv'
```

In rails 3.1 this specifies the format in the html link (format=csv) and it is caught by a respond_with, but in 3.2.2 the format never makes it into the link. I scanned through the list of commits on github and can't find anything that relates to this.

Edit:

Looks like this is an issue with url_for

```
#rails 3.1
url_for :controller=>'posts', :action=>'index', :format=>:xml
/admin/posts/index?format=xml

#rails 3.2.2
url_for :controller=>'posts', :action=>'index', :format=>:xml
/admin/posts/index

#rails 3.2.2
url_for :controller=>'posts', :action=>'index', :format=>:xml, :id => 5
/admin/posts/index/5.xml
```

Comment: Did you ever get around this? I'm experiencing the same thing. Only with named routes I could do something like `<%= link_to "something", something_path(something, :format => :xml) %>`

Comment: Yea I ended up using a hack similar to what you have. I don't remember exactly but I think I physically put the location in the link like `:action => 'index.xml'`, that doesn't feel right though.

Answer (score 13):

Try using `:format => :csv`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to#32-Link-to-same-URL-with-different-format

Comment: Nope. I also tried using a resource path: `documents_path(:format => :csv)` but that sends me to documents.csv instead of adding it as a param.

Comment: `link_to 'cvs', :action => 'show', :format => :csv` I tried it now, it works for me perfectly.

Comment: I just tried that exact link in another controller and its still not working, but its adding the &format=xml for you ? Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem while upgrading from Rails 3.0 to 3.2.17.

From what I see, the problem was not (as the other answers suggest) about the way parameters to `link_to` were specified, but had to do with the definition of the routes in `routes.rb`. It looks like in 3.2, the `:format` parameter can only be passed through as a URL suffix. If there is no route that maps `:format`to the URL, then it will be ignored by `link_to`. 3.0 would have added `format` as an HTTP parameter, in such a case. 3.2 doesn't do that anymore.

My solution was to change my original default route from

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

into

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id)(.:format))'
```

The original definition covered URLs like `/admin/posts/index/5.xml`, but not `/admin/posts/index.xml`. This looks like the same symptom as in the original question here.

After I applied the change, the `:format` was also included into URLs that didn't have an `id` in them.