# Rails setting :format in (ActionController)_path( @user, format: => "csv" )?

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-3.2, link-to

I am following a [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel) to add in the ability to download a csv for different content in our admin area. I have the file downloading when I go to the url, so I am trying to set up the link for it now and I am running into problems trying to set the format of the path request. I think my main issue is that I am passing in the mission object for the path with the format. Since in the rails cast it just has it as

```
<%= link_to "CSV", product_path( format: "csv")%>
```

But trying to set the format like this gives me the same wrong url (as shown below trying a different way of setting format). I have tried a few different ways and tried to find documentation on the parameters _path can take in but every way I have tried so far to set the format has not worked. (I am pretty sure this is an issue specific to Rails 3.2)

This is my exact [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420202/specifiying-a-format-in-link-to-doesnt-work-in-rails-3-2-2) pretty much, but the one answer didn't work as shown below. The answer didn't work for the person who asked the question either...

```
<%= link_to "Users csv", admin_missions_path(@admin_mission, :format => :csv) %>
```

but this turns the link url into:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/missions.52aa6bc61858f041b1000010
```

When it needs to be:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/missions/52aa6bc61858f041b1000010.csv
```

When I go to the right url ending in .csv it automatically downloads the .csv so I know everything works. I just can't figure out how to get the format of the link to work so it downloads the file instead of going to the first wrong url...

Any insight or help would be greatly apprecaited.

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is not that great of a solution... but in my case the link I wanted was just adding the .csv to the end of the url of that page (to process the .csv for the content on that page)

So I just used the request_url and added the .csv postfix... Looks a little jank to me but it works...

```
<%= link_to "Users csv", request.original_url+".csv" %>
```

Referenced this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails) for a list of the different ways to get the current url in different version of Ruby.